# Prevent access to drives from My Computer in Windows but allow browsing desktop

Tags: windows, windows-10

We have enabled GPO: Prevent access to drives from My Computer and restricted all drives. When a user trys to save a picture from Internet Explorer or Microsoft Edge gets an error "This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer. Please contact your system administrator"

The user then clicks ok and still can save the picture on Desktop.

We were wondering if it is possible to hide this error message becuase we want the user to be able to save to his/her desktop?

Or any other way to restrict access to all drives but exclude users desktops?

OS: Windows 10 1709

Comment: Configure the default download location for the browser to be the user’s desktop

Comment: It is already Users Desktop and the user can save to desktop but first gets the error and user must clck ok to cloes the error window.

Comment: I bet if you disable the policy, and have a user try downloading a file, you will find the default download location isn’t the desktop